# Unable to update domain, domain is already in use on server

Tags: domains, godaddy

I'm not 100% sure if this will be the best StackExchange community to ask this question and I apologize if it is not.

I am trying to configure my GoDaddy Main Account Domain Name but when I try to change it to my Main Domain Name it comes with this errors:

> Unable to update domain, franciscocalisto.me is already in use on
>   server

As you can see in the next image:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried calling GoDaddy?? Their tech support is fairly good. Sometimes, not all of the people who answer the phone understand the problem, most will, however they can get a supervisor or ask one of the expert techs there. They have always been able to handle issues that I have had which were never simple ones.

Comment: Not yet but I will do so, as soon as I have time for, right now I have other priorities, but thanks.

Comment: You may find that if you aren't the original owner of the domain, it was hosted previously at godaddy and is still in their system.  As @closetnoc suggested, contact them.

Comment: I am the original owner and it is hosted in goddady since the begging.

Comment: Do you by chance have two accounts with godaddy? one for the main domain name and one for the current domain?

Comment: try to call their phone support, if you still cannot get an answer then maybe its time to find a new hosting provider

Comment: No I just have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I called [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com) and in the beggining we try again the first solution:

> Change your account's primary domain:
>   mydomain

What they said is that when a domain is already in used, even by the same host, you can't change the account primary domain.

However we have a solution. You just need to remove the domain name from your host and add it again.

That way I suggest:

1) BackUp all of your files;

2) Remove the domain and sub-domains of that domain to the host;

3) Add again the domain to the new account primary domain;

[image]

I hope this will help more then me.